# Bash script: compare paths issue

Tags: bash, shell-scripting

I'm working on the bash script that iterates over the list of files. 
I need to compare the paths to this files with the array containing the restricted paths.

Inside the for loop I get a path to a file like this:

```
dname="$(dirname "$i")";
```

This returns me a relative path like path/to/file

The list of restricted paths is stored in the array:

```
restricted=(
   path/to/file
   another/path/to/file
);
```

Then I'm trying to compare the paths:

```
if [[ "${restricted[*]}" = "$dname" ]]; then

//do some things

fi
```

However the comparison does not seem to work.

Could you please advise how to solve the issue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate over the elements of the array something like

```
for i in "${restricted[@]}"
do
    if [ "$i" == "$ddame" ] ; then
        echo "Found"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Is there any way NOT to iterate over the array? Why doesn't my code work though it works for the array of restricted files: if [[ "${fnames[*]}" =~ "$filename" ]]; then ... - this works.

Comment: I've no idea, this is what I would do.

Comment: '==' with [ is incorrect, the operator is =.  Some shells accept it, and others don't, meaning the comparison silently fails.

Answer (score 0):

Iain's answer is the official and best one.  When I write scripts, that's what I use.  However, here is an alternative.  It's not wrong with a capital "W", but I'd still wouldn't really recommend it.

```
if $(echo "${restricted[@]}" | grep -sw "${dname}") ; then
      echo "found"
 else
      echo "not found"
fi
```

This echos your array, pipes the output to grep, which will only match a whole word (`-w`) and will provide no output (`-s`), instead indicating via the exit code that there was/was not a match.  That exit code is what you use as the test for the if statement.

Note that this method has the same glaring issue as your `=~` example you posted for the file name.  It will match on directories that contain your string as a subcomponent.  eg:  */path/to/file/subfolder* and */usr/local/path/to/file* will both match.  (The slashes count as non-word delimiters to grep's `-w`)  The partial match selector of `=~` you're using for your file names will have the same issue.

Comment: If you're going to do that you might find http://stackoverflow.com/a/3689445/353608 interesting.

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly compare an array with a variable; it expands to:

```
[ "one two three" = "two" ]
```

Looking at that, I'm sure you can see the problem!

Perhaps:

```
case "${restricted[*]}" in
$ddname|* $ddname|* $ddname *|$ddname *)
    # do something
    ;;
esac
```

Untested, you may need quotes on the testing line.

Otherwise, iteration is the only method.